# Getting tables with no rows without counting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a huge PostgreSQL database with lots of tables. I want learn all empty tables without counting each tables for performance reasons (Some of the tables have several millions rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will give you an approximate result, but does not include counting table rows.

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class JOIN pg_namespace ON (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid) WHERE relpages = 0 AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'public';
```

This will work best after a `VACUUM ANALYZE`.

Comment: You mean ANALYZE, that's the proces that takes a look at the live tuples. VACUUM takes care of the death ones.

Answer (score 1):

as per http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting , one solution is to first find the tables with small 'reltuples' via

```
select relname from pg_class where reltuples < X
```

and then test for emptiness only those.

Comment: ivancho how can I apply it for all tables with table names in one query?

Comment: as per jmz's answer, you can just directly ask for reltuples/relpages to be equal to zero, but this will only work when database has had time to settle down and update its catalog info

Answer (score 0):

so u want to see table structure, right? try  [pg admin](http://www.pgadmin.org/)

u can open table and see all structure eg datatype, index, function and etc

Comment: select * from anyTable limit 1; would give u result